# R with/without dplyr: create new columns as combinations of prev. columns per row

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
A B C
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 0 0
```

I would want to product the following derivative using dplyr (or other lib):

```
A B C AB AC BC
1 0 1 0  1  0
0 1 1 0  0  1
1 0 0 0  0  0
```

So, I would want to automatically create new columns in the data frame, where their values will be the products of the initial column set (so in this case 3 products for each row - A*B, A*C and B*C). The gist is to do that automatically (I have 6 columns I can't code all combinations). The names of automatically created columns should have some naming scheme since I will need to filter them later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get the column combination and then use a for loop to create new columns.

```
# Create example data frame
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C
1 0 1
                  0 1 1
                  1 0 0",
                  header = TRUE)

# Create the column name combination
m <- combn(names(dat), m = 2)

# Create new columns
for (i in 1:ncol(m)){
  dat[paste(m[, i], collapse = "")] <- dat[m[1, i]] * dat[m[2, i]]
}

dat
#   A B C AB AC BC
# 1 1 0 1  0  1  0
# 2 0 1 1  0  0  1
# 3 1 0 0  0  0  0
```

Comment: It's always a pain that you can't take advantage of `combn`'s `FUN=` argument for this sort of thing to get a named output. You can get so close with `combn(dat, 2, FUN=do.call, what=\`*\`)` but it's not quite there.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: @www, could you please explain `for (i in 1:ncol(m)){
  dat[paste(m[, i], collapse = "")] <- dat[m[1, i]] * dat[m[2, i]]` part please?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 We use a for loop to loop from 1 to the column numbers of `m`. For each time, dat[paste(m[, i], collapse = "")] creates a new column. The name of the new column is paste(m[, i], collapse = ""), which is like `AB`, `AC`, or `BC`. `dat[m[1, i]] * dat[m[2, i]]` is the way to select and multiply two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's best to code without thinking too hard:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 0, 1), 
                 B = c(0, 1, 0),
                 C = c(1, 1, 0))
J <- K <- seq_along(df)
J_n <- K_n <- names(df)

for (j in J) {
  for (k in K) {
    if (j < k) {
      j_name <- J_n[j]
      k_name <- K_n[k]
      df[[paste0(j_name, k_name)]] <- df[[j]] * df[[k]]
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes that the new names are not present in the original data frame. So if your original data frame contained columns `A`, `B`, and `AB`, this won't work.